# Get Queue Attributes not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get the approximate number of messages currently available in an SQS Queue. According to the documentation, I need to use getQueueAttributes, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var params = {
  QueueUrl : queueUrl,
  AttributeName : 'ApproximateNumberOfMessages'
}

sqs.getQueueAttributes(params, function(err, data){
  console.log(data)
  //console.log(data.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages)
})
```

It keeps on returning null for data.

Answer (score 9):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It needs to be an array called AttributeNames. With an "s" at the end.

```
var params = {
  QueueUrl : queueUrl,
  AttributeNames : ['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']
}
```